# IF COL_LENGTH(...) IS NOT NULL does not prevent "Invalid column name" error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a SQL Server patch script for updating multiple databases with with identical structure but possible different versions.

First I check if a column has been removed, if not, I want to update the new version of the column with its inverse (byte) value before deleting. In my world this check should prevent any error if the column does not exist:

```
IF COL_LENGTH('TestTable', 'masterByte') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    -- Update currentByte based on the inversion of masterByte:
    UPDATE dbo.TestTable
    SET currentByte = ~masterByte;
END
GO
```

but in SQL Server Management Studio 19 I get the following error message when the masterByte column does not exist:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
> Invalid column name 'masterByte'

Why do I get this error after specifically saying that I only want to run the command `IF masterByte IS NOT NULL`? How could I correct my code to perform the desired task without causing an error whenever `masterByte` is not present?

Script for creating a simple test database:

```
CREATE DATABASE TestDB;
GO

USE TestDB;
GO

CREATE TABLE TestTable 
(
    currentByte TINYINT
);
GO
```

Comment: No, it won't because it's a *compile time* error.  Deferring compilation only occurs on *some* scenarios, and columns that don't exist on tables that *do* isn't one of them. This is expected behaviour.

Comment: SQL Server validates columns for existing tables, so already when it parses the query and can't find masterByte column, it fails with the above error. The solution i use it to wrap the lines inside dynamic sql, or use a better tool to handle migrations such as above